# When listening to a port (taskserver) should the local address be `localhost` or `0.0.0.0`?

Tags: linux, networking, ip, port, localhost

I've been trying to make a `taskd` server work on my computer (Arch Linux) for days. The problem I'm facing now is that `taskd`'s config documentation (https://taskwarrior.org/docs/taskserver/troubleshooting-sync.html) says that I have to use the output of `hostname -f` as an address (I do not know what 'CN' abbreviates). I've also tried with my local IP address starting with `192.168` but that gave me the handshake error you can find in the troubleshooting guide I linked.

I started investigating a little, because I couldn't access my taskserver from other machines. I found this:

When I listen to the port I use, let it be `54000`, using `nc -l -p 54000`, I can see this as the output of `ss -lntu | grep 54000`:

```
tcp    LISTEN   0        10                0.0.0.0:54000          0.0.0.0:*
```

Whereas when I start `taskd`, which listens on the same port, `ss` gives me:

```
tcp    LISTEN   0        4               127.0.0.1:54000          0.0.0.0:*
```

---

Now from a different machine, I tried checking the port while listening with `nc -vv 192.168.x.y 54000` (with the server's IP address) and I found that when the local address is `0.0.0.0`, the port shows as open. Otherwise it shows up as closed. I think this is because `127.0.0.1` is essentially `localhost` and I can't see that from my network?

`taskd` also has a config file with a server option where I entered the output of `hostname -f`, which is `watermelon.localdomain`, as I was instructed by the documentation. I suppose that's what's translated to `localhost`, right?

I would greatly appreciate your help, thanks in advance!

---

## UPDATE 2018/04/21

I managed to solve the problem by setting the `server` variable in the config to `0.0.0.0:54000`, this way I got `taskd` to listen for any address on port `54000`. Now everything works beautifully. The documentation of `taskd` was a bit vague on the topic I guess.

Comment: `CN` is an abbreviation for `Common Name` (usually a fully qualified domain name). So if `hostname -f` returns *watermelon.localdomain*, the instructions are saying to use e.g. `CN=watermelon.localdomain`. According to the taskd website, `CN=localhost` is the default value and thus is not valid.

Regarding `127.0.0.1` vs. `0.0.0.0`, `127.0.0.1` is a local loopback address and typically indicates the port is only available to processes on the same machine. In contrast, `0.0.0.0` in this case effectively means "all IPv4 addresses on the local machine" (incl. any IP that is network-accessible).

Comment: Concerning the configuration files, my understanding is that the entry should be something like e.g. `taskd.server=watermelon.localdomain:54000` (but I could be wrong).

Comment: @Anaksunaman I think you're right... But why does the server listen on the loopback address then? I don't get it.

Comment: My assumption would be that `127.0.0.1` is likely the first (or only) IPv4 address available to *watermelon.localdomain* (assuming you are using that in your configuration). The `taskd` website does indicate you can potentially use e.g. *your_network_ip:54000* (vs. e.g *watermelon.localdomain:54000*) - https://taskwarrior.org/docs/taskserver/protocol.html

Comment: @Anaksunaman I managed to solve the problem --- I was really dumb it seems (see updated question). Thanks for your help!

Comment: You're welcome. I am glad you got everything working correctly. =)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sockets are configured to listen on a specific IP and Port. There are typically two primary configurations you would use for a Socket and a third that isn't as common, but comes in handy.

1) To only allow communication from the machine running the service

This is configured when you see `127.0.0.1:54000`. **ONLY** the host machine can access this service. You can use something like a reverse proxy to allow access externally, but nothing on the network will be allowed to connect to it.

2) To all machines on any network reachable from the server

This is configured when you see `0.0.0.0:54000`. This allows anything to talk to this service as long as the packets can get to it.

3) To only a specific network the server is joined to

This is configured when you see `192.168.0.2:54000` (or whatever IP). This means that **ONLY** this *subnet* of this network is allowed access.

If you want to allow your service to be connected from other machines on the network, it needs to be bound on `0.0.0.0` or the local IP.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer! Do you have any idea how I should make `taskd` listen on `0.0.0.0` then?

Comment: it's likely in the config for `taskd`. Look for some kind of entry indicating 'bind port' or 'bind address'. It might be listed as `127.0.0.1:54000` already. But the best thing is to check the docs for `taskd`

Comment: I found this relevant question just now: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44902884/taskwarrior-port-not-opening-externally

The answerer mentions 'ensuring /etc/hosts was set with the externally facing IP addresses'. Could you please explain what that means and whether that is a good idea? It seems to have worked for the OP of that question.

Comment: `/etc/hosts` has no impact on the service's ability for other hosts to connect. It does allow the local machine to properly reference iteslf, but there should be no reason to change it as long as the hostname still matches the systems' configured hostname.

Comment: I managed to solve the problem since (see updated question). You helped a lot though, thanks.